# IllegalStateException: Cannot apply ... to already built object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring-boot in version 1.5.6.RELEASE

I'm getting following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer@6b5c38ed to already built object
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.add(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:196)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.apply(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:133)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.apply(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:290)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java:134)
    at com.mca.security.configurer.auth.FirstAuthenticationManagerConfigurer.configure(FirstAuthenticationManagerConfigurer.java:12)
    at com.mca.security.configurer.auth.FirstAuthenticationManagerConfigurer.configure(FirstAuthenticationManagerConfigurer.java:7)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:384)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:330)
```

I've managed to reproduce it in here:

https://github.com/mironbalcerzak/spring-boot-security-issue

Idea behind the implementation is very simple.
I wish to create few SecurityConfigurer's (both for HttpSecurity and AuthenticationManagerBuilder) and combine them using apply() in class extending WebSecurityAdapter.

Correct me if I am wrong and that's not the way to do it.

Workaround I found is extracting "apply" method to SecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(...), and in SecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(...) operating on already created object.

Here's the workaround (that makes me very unhappy :) )

```
public class FirstAuthenticationManagerConfigurer
        extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<AuthenticationManager, AuthenticationManagerBuilder> {

    private DaoAuthenticationConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder, UserDetailsManager> configurer;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> managerConfigurer = builder.inMemoryAuthentication();
        managerConfigurer.withUser("user1").password("password").roles("SYSTEM");
        UserDetailsManager userDetailsService = managerConfigurer.getUserDetailsService();
        configurer = builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        configurer.configure(builder);
    }
}
```

...have a good day guys and happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

To configure Spring Security **In-Memory Authentication**,
add **UserDetailsService** bean in your **SecurityConfiguration** class, with User Name and Password for authentication.

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() 
    {
        //User Role
        UserDetails theUser = User.withUsername("sergey")
                                  .passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()::encode)
                                  .password("12345678").roles("USER").build();
    
        //Manager Role 
        UserDetails theManager = User.withUsername("john")
                                     .passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()::encode)
                                    .password("12345").roles("MANAGER").build();
    

       InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
          
       userDetailsManager.createUser(theUser);
       userDetailsManager.createUser(theManager);
    
       return userDetailsManager;
   }
}
```

**Reference Document:** https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/spring-security-in-memory-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` in `@EnableWebSecurity` annotated configuration.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/issues/189